# Removing url fragment from NSURL

Tags: cocoa, nsurl

I'm writing a Cocoa application, which uses NSURLs -- I need to remove the fragment portion of the URL (the #BLAH part).

example:  http://example.com/#blah should end up as http://example.com/

I found some code in WebCore that seems to do it by using CFURL functionality, but it never finds the fragment portion in the URL.  I've encapsulated it in a extension category:

```
-(NSURL *)urlByRemovingComponent:(CFURLComponentType)component {
    CFRange fragRg = CFURLGetByteRangeForComponent((CFURLRef)self, component, NULL);
    // Check to see if a fragment exists before decomposing the URL.
    if (fragRg.location == kCFNotFound)
        return self;

    UInt8 *urlBytes, buffer[2048];
    CFIndex numBytes = CFURLGetBytes((CFURLRef)self, buffer, 2048);
    if (numBytes == -1) {
        numBytes = CFURLGetBytes((CFURLRef)self, NULL, 0);
        urlBytes = (UInt8 *)(malloc(numBytes));
        CFURLGetBytes((CFURLRef)self, urlBytes, numBytes);
    } else
        urlBytes = buffer;

    NSURL *result = (NSURL *)CFMakeCollectable(CFURLCreateWithBytes(NULL, urlBytes, fragRg.location - 1, kCFStringEncodingUTF8, NULL));
    if (!result)
        result = (NSURL *)CFMakeCollectable(CFURLCreateWithBytes(NULL, urlBytes, fragRg.location - 1, kCFStringEncodingISOLatin1, NULL));

    if (urlBytes != buffer) free(urlBytes);
    return result ? [result autorelease] : self;
}
-(NSURL *)urlByRemovingFragment {
    return [self urlByRemovingComponent:kCFURLComponentFragment];
}
```

This is used as such:

```
NSURL *newUrl = [[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/#blah"] urlByRemovingFragment];
```

unfortunately, newUrl ends up being "http://example.com/#blah" because the first line in urlByRemovingComponent always returns kCFNotFound

I'm stumped.  Is there a better way of going about this?

**Working Code, thanks to nall**

```
-(NSURL *)urlByRemovingFragment {
    NSString *urlString = [self absoluteString];
    // Find that last component in the string from the end to make sure to get the last one
    NSRange fragmentRange = [urlString rangeOfString:@"#" options:NSBackwardsSearch];
    if (fragmentRange.location != NSNotFound) {
        // Chop the fragment.
        NSString* newURLString = [urlString substringToIndex:fragmentRange.location];
        return [NSURL URLWithString:newURLString];
    } else {
        return self;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this:

```
NSString* s = @"http://www.somewhere.org/foo/bar.html/#label";
NSURL* u = [NSURL URLWithString:s];

// Get the last path component from the URL. This doesn't include
// any fragment.
NSString* lastComponent = [u lastPathComponent];

// Find that last component in the string from the end to make sure
// to get the last one
NSRange fragmentRange = [s rangeOfString:lastComponent
                                 options:NSBackwardsSearch];

// Chop the fragment.
NSString* newURLString = [s substringToIndex:fragmentRange.location + fragmentRange.length];

NSLog(@"%@", s);
NSLog(@"%@", newURLString);
```

Comment: close. apparently lastPathComponent does return the fragment, and is a  NSString method. I've posted the final code to the question.

Comment: NSURL also has a lastPathComponent which doesn't return the fragment, but it's 10.6+ http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000301-SW22

Comment: What if the last path component is within the fragment (e.g. those rich fragment URLs some web apps have)?

Answer (score 2):

This is quite an old question, and it has already been answered, but for another simple option this is how I did it:

```
 NSString* urlAsString = [myURL absoluteString];
 NSArray* components = [urlAsString componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"];
 NSURL* myURLminusFragment = [NSURL URLWithString: components[0]];
```

if there is no fragment, urlMinusFragment will be the same as myURL

Comment: Nice simple solution, but you may want to switch to using components.firstObject if your iOS/OSX version supports it.  Its safer than explicitly accessing components[0], even though componentsSeparatedByString: *should* always return a non-empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3.0

this will remove the fragment

```
if let fragment = url.fragment{
  url = URL(string: url.absoluteString.replacingOccurrences(of: "#\(fragment)", with: "")!
}
```